# Creating a minimal graph representing all combinations of 3-bit binary strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have an algorithm that creates a graph that has all representations of 3-bit binary strings encoded in the form of the shortest graph paths, where an even number in the path means 0, while an odd number means 1:

```
from itertools import permutations, product
import networkx as nx
import progressbar
import itertools

def groups(sources, template):
    func = permutations
    keys = sources.keys()
    combos = [func(sources[k], template.count(k)) for k in keys]
    for t in product(*combos):
        d = {k: iter(n) for k, n in zip(keys, t)}
        yield [next(d[k]) for k in template]                                      

g = nx.Graph()

added = []   
good = []
index = []
# I create list with 3-bit binary strings
# I do not include one of the pairs of binary strings that have a mirror image
list_1 = [list(i) for i in itertools.product(tuple(range(2)), repeat=3) if tuple(reversed(i)) >= tuple(i)]
count = list(range(len(list_1)))

h = 0
while len(added) < len(list_1): 
     # In each next step I enlarge the list 'good` by the next even and odd number
     if h != 0:   
        for q in range(2):   
            good.append([i for i in good if i%2 == q][-1] + 2)
     # I create a list `c` with string indices from the list` list_1`, that are not yet used.
     # Whereas the `index` list stores the numbering of strings from the list` list_1`, whose representations have already been correctly added to the `added` list.          
     c = [item for item in count if item not in index]

     for m in c:
     # I create representations of binary strings, where 0 is 'v0' and 1 is 'v1'. For example, the '001' combination is now 'v0v0v1'
         a = ['v{}'.format(x%2) for x in list_1[m]]

         if h == 0:
            for w in range(2):
                if len([i for i in good if i%2 == w]) < a.count('v{}'.format(w)):
                   for j in range(len([i for i in good if i%2 == w]), a.count('v{}'.format(w))):
                       good.insert(j,2*j + w)                       

         sources={}
         for x in range(2):
             sources["v{0}".format(x)] = [n for n in good if n%2 == x]
         # for each representation in the form 'v0v0v1' for example, I examine all combinations of strings where 'v0' is an even number 'a' v1 'is an odd number, choosing values from the' dobre2 'list and checking the following conditions.
         for aaa_binary in groups(sources, a):             
             # Here, the edges and nodes are added to the graph from the combination of `aaa_binary` and checking whether the combination meets the conditions. If so, it is added to the `added` list. If not, the newly added edges are removed and the next `aaa_binary` combination is taken.           
             g.add_nodes_from (aaa_binary)
             t1 = (aaa_binary[0],aaa_binary[1])
             t2 = (aaa_binary[1],aaa_binary[2]) 

             added_now = []                      
             for edge in (t1,t2):
                 if not g.has_edge(*edge):
                    g.add_edge(*edge)
                    added_now.append(edge)

             added.append(aaa_binary)
             index.append(m)

             for f in range(len(added)):
                 if nx.shortest_path(g, aaa_binary[0], aaa_binary[2]) != aaa_binary or nx.shortest_path(g, added[f][0], added[f][2]) != added[f]:
                    for edge in added_now:
                        g.remove_edge(*edge)
                    added.remove(aaa_binary)
                    index.remove(m)
                    break
             # Calling a good combination search interrupt if it was found and the result added to the `added` list, while the index from the list 'list_1` was added to the` index` list              
             if m in index:
                break

     good.sort()
     set(good)
     index.sort() 

     h = h+1
```

Output paths representing 3-bit binary strings from `added`:

```
[[0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [0, 3, 6], [3, 0, 7]]
```

So these are representations of 3-bit binary strings:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Where in the step `h = 0` the first 4 sub-lists were found, and in the step `h = 1` the last two sub-lists were added.

Of course, as you can see, there are no reflections of the mirrored strings, because there is no such need in an undirected graph.

Graph:

[image]

The above solution creates a minimal graph and with the unique shortest paths. This means that one combination of a binary string has only one representation on the graph in the form of the shortest path. So the choice of a given path is a single-pointing indication of a given binary sequence.

Now I would like to use multiprocessing on the `for m in c` loop, because the order of finding elements does not matter here.

I try to use multiprocessing in this way:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

added = []

def foo(i):
    added = []
       # do something 
       added.append(x[i])
    return added

if __name__ == '__main__':

h = 0
while len(added)<len(c): 

   pool = Pool(4)
   result = pool.imap_unordered(foo, c)      
   added.append(result[-1])

   pool.close()
   pool.join()

   h = h + 1
```

Multiprocessing takes place in the while-loop, and in the `foo` function, the
`added` list is created. In each subsequent step `h` in the loop, the list`added` should be incremented by subsequent values, and the current list `added` should be used in the function`foo`. Is it possible to pass the current contents of the list to the function in each subsequent step of the loop? Because in the above code, the `foo` function creates the new contents of the `added` list from scratch each time. How can this be solved?

Which in consequence gives bad results:

```
[[0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 3]]
```

Because for such a graph, nodes and edges, the condition is not met that `nx.shortest_path (graph, i, j) == added[k]` for every final nodes `i, j` from `added[k] for k in added list`.

Where for `h = 0` to the elements `[0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 5]` are good, while elements added in the step`h = 1`, ie `[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 3]` are evidently found without affecting the elements from the previous step.

How can this be solved?

I realize that this is a type of sequential algorithm, but I am also interested in partial solutions, i.e. parallel processes even on parts of the algorithm. For example, that the steps of `h` while looping run sequentially, but the`for m in c` loop is multiprocessing. Or other partial solutions that will improve the entire algorithm for larger combinations.

I will be grateful for showing and implementing some idea for the use of multiprocessing in my algorithm.

Comment: Naming your variables in English and with descriptive names would greatly help in reading the code, and in devising a solution. Alternatively you could add a few comments here and there on what the different routines are attempting to do.

Comment: Ok I will try to edit the query.

Comment: please take into account the fixed indentation, also it would help if you could provide a _minimal_ working example. Is `ProgressBar` needed for the logic of the algorithm?

Comment: `ProgressBar` he is not needed. I used it only to track how the algorithm behaves. What do you mean by a `minimal working example`?

Comment: @Matti Lyra I added some comments in the code itself.

Comment: minimal working example 1) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: I thought so, but this is the smallest example :)

Comment: I have removed only the part responsible for drawing the graph.

Comment: `ProgressBar` is completely unnecessary, it's 2 lines of code, but those two lines are not central to what you are asking. Whenever you ask a question, you're asking people to spend anywhere between 30 minutes to hours in thinking about _your_ problem and suggesting solutions. The least you can do for them is to provide source code that is well formatted, clear and runnable. Don't waste _my_ time by including lines of code that I do not need to know about in order to solve _your_ problem!

Comment: I removed the progressbar. the program is possible to run. on the other hand, it seemed to me that I improved readability, but apparently not yet ;)

Comment: there was a variable name error in one place and that's why the program did not work, I've already corrected it.

Comment: Your actual problem still seems to have nothing to do with the specific field of application. Make an example of the problem that allows people reasoning about it without having to understand graph theory.

Comment: you can pass in the `added` list using a partial function as the callable or using `pool.starmap` - that's not really the answer though as I think the algorithm itself needs to be refactored to make it parallelisable - it would really help to know what `list_1`, `good`, `h`, `q`, `c`, `w`, `m`, `a` conceptually represent and/or contain - `good` or `list_1` as names don't really give away what the _function_ of those lists is meant to be.

Comment: @Darkonaut that's why I thought it necessary to additionally assign a prize to the question, because the question is quite complex. and in the question itself there is not much theory of graphs, only the concept of the shortest path. and the concept of the shortest path is so intuitive that I do not have to probably explain it specifically :)

Comment: @Matti Lyra yes, factorization would probably come in handy;)

Comment: The graph in the question has 26 paths of length 3. That's counting mirrored paths, e.g. both `6,3,1` and `1,3,6` are counted. After removing mirrored paths, there are 13 paths of length 3, when only 6 are needed. So the graph is not minimal, which is to say that it does not have only one shortest path for each binary string. For example, both `6,3,1` and `0,3,5` translate to `011`.

Comment: @user3386109 I used the word `minimal` because of the least number of nodes used to build a graph that has all the representations of 3-bit binary strings as unambiguous shortest paths. But the shortest paths with a given feature can be more than one if it does not destroy the general condition of the graph, and will save you as regards the number of nodes.

Comment: Because if I would like to stick to the meaning of the standard minimal, that is, there would be only one shortest path with a given feature, then I would have to use more nodes to present such a situation.

Comment: There is a graph with 8 nodes that contains exactly 6 paths (12 if you count mirrors) of length 3. And that graph contains all 6 of the 3-bit binary strings.

Comment: That's what I mean. And I need some more optimal approach, or using multiprocessing, because in the future I'm interested in n-bit paths. Do you say that it already exists in graph theory? that would probably solve my problem :)

Comment: @user3386109 Of course, an important feature of this graph is that each such path can be obtained by specifying only the first and last value of the path. That is, for example, if we have one of the shortest paths in the form `[a, b, c]`, then we can get it with `nx.shortest_path (g, a, c) ---> [a, b, c] `.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can parallelise the code as it is currently. The part that you're wanting to parallelise, the `for m in c` loop accesses three lists that are global `good`, `added` and `index` and the graph `g` itself. You could use a `multiprocessing.Array` for the lists, but that would undermine the whole point of parallelisation as `multiprocessing.Array` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array)) is synchronised, so the processes would not actually be running in parallel.

So, the code needs to be refactored. My preferred way of parallelising algorithms is to use a kind of a producer / consumer pattern

1. initialisation to set up a job queue that needs to be executed (runs sequentially)
2. have a pool of workers that all pull jobs from that queue (runs in parallel)
3. after the job queue has been exhausted, aggregate results and build up the final solution (runs sequentially)

In this case `1.` would be the setup code for `list_1`, `count` and probably the `h == 0` case. After that you would build a queue of "*job orders*", this would be the `c` list -> pass that list to a bunch of workers -> get the results back and aggregate. The problem is that each execution of the `for m in c` loop has access to global state *and* the global state changes after each iteration. This logically means that you can not run the code in parallel, because the first iteration changes the global state and affects what the second iteration does. That is, by definition, a sequential algorithm. You can not, at least not easily, parallelise an algorithm that iteratively builds a graph.

You could use `multiprocessing.starmap` and `multiprocessing.Array`, but that doesn't solve the problem. You still have the graph `g` which is also shared between all processes. So the whole thing would need to be refactored in such a way that each iteration over the `for m in c` loop is independent of any other iteration of that loop *or* the entire logic has to be changed so that the `for m in c` loop is not needed to begin with.

---

**UPDATE**

---

I was thinking that you could possibly turn the algorithm towards a slightly less sequential version with the following changes. I'm pretty sure the code already does something rather similar, but the code is a little too dense for me and graph algorithms aren't exactly my specialty.

Currently, for a new triple (`'101'` for instance), you're generating all possible connection points in the existing graph, then adding the new triple to the graph and eliminating nodes based on measuring shortest paths. This requires checking for shortest paths on the graph *and* modifying, which prevents parallelisation.

*NOTE: what follows is a pretty rough outline for how the code could be refactored, I haven't tested this or verified mathematically that it actually works correctly*

*NOTE 2: In the below discussion `'101'` (notice the quotes `''` is a binary string, so is `'00'` and `'1'` where as `1`, `0`, `4` and so on (without quotes) are vertex labels in the graph.*

What if, you instead were to do a kind of a substring search on the existing graph, I'll use the first triple as an example. To initialise

1. generate a `job_queue` which contains all triples
2. take the first one and insert that, for instance, `'000'` which would be (`0`, `2`, `4`) - this is trivial no need to check anything because the graph is empty when you start so the shortest path is by definition the one you insert.

At this point you also have partial paths for `'011'`, `'001'`, `'010'` and conversely (`'110'` and `'001'` because the graph is undirected). We're going to utilise the fact that the existing graph contains sub-solutions to remaining triples in `job_queue`. Let's say the next triple is `'010'`, you iterate over the binary string `'010'` or `list('010')`

- if a path/vertex for `'0'` already exists in the graph --> continue
- if a path/vertices for `'01'` already exists in the graph --> continue
- if a path/vertices for `'010'` exists you're done, no need to add anything (this is actually a failure case: `'010'` should not have been in the job queue anymore because it was already solved).

The second bullet point would fail because `'01'` does not exist in the graph. Insert `'1'` which in this case would be node `1` to the graph and connect it to one of the three `even` nodes, I don't think it matters which one *but* you have to record which one it was connected to, let's say you picked `0`. The graph now looks something like

```
 0 - 2 - 4
  \  * 
   \ * 
    \*
     1
```

The optimal edge to complete the path is `1 - 2` (marked with stars) to get a path `0 - 1 - 2` for `'010'`, this is the path that maximises the number of triples encoded, if the edge `1-2` is added to the graph. If you add `1-4` you encode only the `'010'` triple, where as `1 - 2` encodes `'010'` but also `'001'` and `'100'`.

As an aside, let's pretend you connected `1` to `2` at first, instead of `0` (the first connection was picked random), you now have a graph

```
 0 - 2 - 4
     | 
     | 
     |
     1
```

and you can connect `1` to either `4` or to `0`, but you again get a graph that encodes the maximum number of triples remaining in `job_queue`.

So how do you check how many triples a potential new path encodes? You can check for this relatively easily *and more importantly* the check can be done in parallel without modifying the graph `g`, for 3bit strings the savings from parallel aren't that big, but for 32bit strings they would be. Here's how it works.

1. (sequential) generate all possible complete paths from the sub-path `0-1` -> `(0-1-2), (0-1-4)`.
2. (parallel) for each potential complete path check how many other triples that path solves, i.e. for each path candidate generate all the triples that the graph solves and check if those triples are still in `job_queue`.

   1. `(0-1-2)` solves two other triples `'001' (4-2-1) or (2-0-1)` and `'100' (1-0-2) or (1-2-4)`.
   2. `(0-1-4)` only solved the triple `'010'`, i.e. itself

the edge/path that solves the most triples remaining in `job_queue` is the optimal solution (I don't have a proof this).

You run `2.` above in parallel copying the graph to each worker. Because you're not modifying the graph, only checking how many triples it solves, you can do this in parallel. Each worker should have a signature something like

```
check_graph(g, path, copy_of_job_queue):
    # do some magic
    return (n_paths_solved, paths_solved)
```

`path` is either `(0-1-2)` or `(0-1-4)`, `copy_of_job_queue` should be a copy of the remaining paths on the `job_queue`. For K workers you create K copies of the queue. Once the worker pool finishes you know which path `(0-1-2)` or `(0-1-4)` solves the most triples.

You *then* add that path and modify the graph, and remove the solved paths from the job queue.

RINSE - REPEAT until job queue is empty.

There's a few obvious problems with the above, for one your doing a lot of copying and looping over of `job_queue`, if you're dealing with large bit spaces, say 32bits, then `job_queue` is pretty long, so you might want to not keep copying to all the workers.

For the parallel step above (2.) you might want to have `job_queue` actually be a `dict` where the key is the triple, say `'010'`, and the value is a boolean flag saying if that triple is already encoded in the graph.

Comment: The sequentiality is the worst. I tried to find a mathematical model for creating such a graph. Depending on the input lengths of the binary strings, the number of nodes used grows according to a certain string, but still I could not find a recipe for creating individual graph paths. Now I'm thinking how to turn an algorithm into a non-sequential algorithm, to give at least similar results, with a similar number of nodes used at the end. But you showed the direction that I can think about.

Comment: Interesting approach. I will write tomorrow, how I will analyze this way more accurately. But I have one comment. Maybe I did not quite understand it, because I have read so quickly for now, but it seems to me that in creating an example graph, the path `0 - 1 - 2` can not be created. Because if it was created then `nx.shortest_path (g, 0, 2)! = [0, 1, 2]`. But output will be [0, 2] `:)

Comment: That's correct. I don't think you need the `shortest_path` check when you're building the graph, the greedy approach I suggest above is a replacement for that. I don't know if I understood the problem statement completely though, do all path encodings need to be unique? `001` in my solution has two encodings `4-2-1` and `2-0-1`.

Comment: I have some doubts whether I have explained the whole problem well because I used `shortest_patch ()` for an important reason. Because, besides being a minimal graph containing the shortest paths representing binary strings, I also want to be able to call them at the lowest possible cost. Use only the endpoints of this path. This means that if I had a 6-bit path in the graph in the form `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`, I would like to get it using only `a and f` points, i.e. `nx.shortest_path (g, a, f) ---> [a, b, c, d, e, f]`.

Comment: Of course, not all encodings have to be unique, it does not matter. But it is important to read these paths later as at the lowest cost.

Comment: OK, well that quite significantly changes the problem description

Comment: I still don't understand the problem with my solution. If you call `shortest_path(g, 0, 2)` on your example graph you also just get `(0, 2)` - what's the problem with that? In fact if you call shortest path on any two adjoining nodes you back those two adjoining nodes, by definition.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a problem with the adjoining nodes, because by definition it must always work. I just have doubts that your design will later protect the longer paths, calling them only by entering the first and last node. Ehh this language. Sometimes I have doubts whether it is simply my language deficiencies that cause a bad understanding of the presented solution :) In some time, I will write on sheet your solution once again and check it out :)

Answer (score 3):

Is there a faster algorithm? Looking at these two trees, (i've represented the numbers in binary to make the paths easier to see). Now to reduce this from 14 nodes to 7 nodes, can you layer the required paths from one tree onto the other? You can add any edge you like to one of the trees as long as it doesn't connect a node with its ancestors.

```
          _ 000
   _ 00 _/
  /      \_ 001
 0        _ 010
  \_ 01 _/
         \_ 011
          _ 100
   _ 10 _/
  /      \_ 101
 1        _ 110
  \_ 11 _/
         \_ 111
```

can you see for example connecting 01 to 00, would be similar to replacing the head of the tree's 0 with 01, and thus with one edge you have added 100, 101 and 110..

Comment: Interesting approach. The case of combining `00` with` 01` and getting rid of the head `0` seems to me to understand. But when I go on outside, I start to looping and I do not see all the possibilities.

Comment: And for now I have never reached 7 nodes once.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the final graph, that only has 7 nodes (labeled 0 or 1), yet is able to generate all 8 strings.

Comment: does connecting 01 to (00, 001, 001)  give you what you need?

Comment: Pretty sure that doesn't work. That would seem to creates cycles of length 3 and a cycle of length 4. The problem with cycles of length 3 is that the shortest path between two nodes will only have one edge. The problem with cycles of length 4 is that you can go two directions around the cycle. So the shortest path is ambiguous.